# MessageBox that allows a process to continue automatically

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

I would like a message box to be displayed and the program to just continue and not wait for me to click ok on this message box. Can it be done ?

```
else
{
    // Debug or messagebox the line that fails
    MessageBox.Show("Cols:" + _columns.Length.ToString() + " Line: " + lines[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the correct solution would be to replace the messagebox with a plain window (or form, if you are using winforms). That would be quite simple. Example (WPF)

```
<Window x:Class="local:MyWindow" ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="{Binding}" />
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   Click="SelfClose">Close</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>

...
class MyWindow : Window
{
    public MyWindow(string message) { this.DataContext = message; }
    void SelfClose(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { this.Close(); }
}

...
new MyWindow("Cols:" + _columns.Length.ToString() + " Line: " + lines[i]).Show();
```

If you want a quick-and-dirty solution, you can just call the messagebox from a throwaway thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => MessageBox("lalalalala"));
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

(not sure if `ApartmentState.STA` is actually needed)

Comment: @Symon: Back at 2012 TPL was a rare guest :) But with a thread you can ensure STA apartment, which is not easy with tasks. UI component generally run in STA. (But for message box there is apparently an exception.) Besides that, message box is a long-lived object (several seconds), so stealing a thread pool thread might be not desirable.

Answer (score 8):

```
//You need to add this if you don't already have it

using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

//Then here is your code that will run async of the main thread;

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
{
   MessageBox.Show("This is a message");

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { MessageBox.Show(this, "text"); }));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wrong: this will block the UI on the _next_ message loop iteration. The OP wants the message box completely asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Threading;    

static void MessageThread()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cols:" + _columns.Length.ToString() + " Line: " + lines[i]);
}

static void MyProgram()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MessageThread));
    t.Start();
}
```

This will start the MessageThread function in it's own thread so the rest of your code in what I called `MyProgram` can continue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

What you want are modeless forms. Here are some [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [samples](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Modeless_Dialogs_in_WinForms.aspx) for you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use Multi Threading to achieve  this task in which one thread (Main Thread) will do processing and other will be used to show the message-box.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using a delegate.

The following snippits are from somthing i've just finished:-

```
namespace YourApp
{
  public partial class frmMain : Form
  {
    // Declare delegate for summary box, frees main thread from dreaded OK click
    private delegate void ShowSummaryDelegate();
    ShowSummaryDelegate ShowSummary;

    /// <summary>
    /// Your message box, edit as needed
    /// </summary>
    private void fxnShowSummary()
    {
      string msg;

      msg = "TEST SEQUENCE COMPLETE\r\n\r\n";
      msg += "Number of tests performed: " + lblTestCount.Text + Environment.NewLine;
      msg += "Number of false positives: " + lblFalsePve.Text + Environment.NewLine;
      msg += "Number of false negatives: " + lblFalseNve.Text + Environment.NewLine;

      MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// This callback is used to cleanup the invokation of the summary delegate.
    /// </summary>
    private void fxnShowSummaryCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
      try
      {
        ShowSummary.EndInvoke(ar);
      }
      catch
      {
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Your bit of code that wants to call a message box
    /// </summary>
    private void tmrAction_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ShowSummary = new ShowSummaryDelegate(fxnShowSummary);
      AsyncCallback SummaryCallback = new AsyncCallback(fxnShowSummaryCallback);
      IAsyncResult SummaryResult = ShowSummary.BeginInvoke(SummaryCallback, null);
    }

    // End of Main Class
  }
}
```